# Mysql Query required with one to many relation for searching with matching

Tags: php, mysql

**First Table**

**Property**

```
id   Name

 1   ABC
 2   XYZ
 3   GHQ
```

**Property_options**

```
 id   property_id  option

 1      1         terrace
 2      1         balcony
 3      1         garaj
 1      2         terrace
 2      2         balcony
 3      2         garaj
```

I want to filter property with three options (`terrace`,  `balcony` and `garaj`)

If user check three options then only those property will come those have three options not two or one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this using aggregation and a `group by`:

```
select p.propertyid
from property p
group by p.propertyid
having sum(property_option = 'terrace') > 0 and
       sum(property_option = 'balcony') > 0 and
       sum(property_option = 'garaj') > 0;
```

Each of the conditions counts the number of times the property appears.  This is a flexible method.  If you wanted the first two, but not a "garaj", you would use:

```
having sum(property_option = 'terrace') > 0 and
       sum(property_option = 'balcony') > 0 and
       sum(property_option = 'garaj') = 0;
```

Comment: I required only one property if all three options are true

Comment: select p.id,p.name
from property p
INNER JOIN property_option po ON p.id = po.property_id
group by p.id
having sum(po.meta_name = 'terrace') > 0 and
       sum(po.meta_name = 'balcony') > 0 and
       sum(po.meta_name = 'garaj') > 0

Comment: How is it not working?  If you want only one match, then add a `limit 1` clause to the query.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select Name from Property where id in (select property_id from Property_Options where Property_Option = 'terrace ' and Property_Option = 'balcony ' and Property_Option = 'garaj')a
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exact answer

select p.id,p.name from property p INNER JOIN property_option po ON p.id = po.property_id group by p.id
having sum(po.meta_name = 'terrace') > 0 and sum(po.meta_name = 'balcony') > 0 and sum(po.meta_name = 'garaj') > 0